# Javacard big numbers and modular arithmetic

Tags: javacard, bignum, modular-arithmetic

I am new in the Javacard ecosystem and I was wondering what's the consensus regarding (modular) computations with big numbers in Javacard.

More specifically, I am looking for a lib which supports modular exponentiation and in general modular arithmetic operations between big numbers.

I am aware of BigNumber and ds.ov2.bignat. However, the first one does not provide methods for modular arithmetic.

ds.ov2.bignat seems to be more relevant, but I wasn't sure if it is common prctice to use bignat or there is another more popular lib.

Thanks!emphasized text

Answer (score 1):

The consensus is kind of *not to* perform modular exponentiation. `bignat` seems to rely on RSA ops for modular arithmetic. Nowadays this should probably be replaced by DH calculations.

But in general, JC is not really the platform to create your own cryptography. Some platform have vendor specific extensions for users to implement their own cryptography.

Smart cards however rely on many protections against side channel attacks. You'd need a very good understanding about cryptography to implement anything for use "in the field".

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is a research project so we do not expect that our applet will be used in commercial settings. Could you please elaborate a little on the RSA ops and what you mean by replacing them with DH calculations? Thanks! :-)

Comment: I think there is already multiple threads to this topic in the javacard section

Answer (score 1):

Responding to update, as the landscape has changed since the last response:

Indeed, at the time there was no library and the previous responses were correct.

This lack of BigNumbers (and other basic functionality) was very annoying so we actually built the library ourselves.

It realizes lots of things that I needed but couldn't find, including BigNumbers. For people who come across this question in the future you can download it here and see if it helps you: [opencryptojc.org](http://opencryptojc.org)